# Count the number of missing values in groups in R

Tags: r

I have a tibble, with many observations and variables.

What I want to do is simply calculate(grouping by variable1 and variable2) the mean of variableXXX,and the total number of missing values for each group.

this is what I have written so far:

```
 data%>%
      group_by(variable1,variable2)%>%
      summarise(mean(variableXXX))
```

how can I calculate the number of missing values for each group? I am new using R, so the easiest solution is better

Answer (score 2):

We can get the `sum` of logical vector created with `is.na`

```
library(dplyr)
data%>%
  group_by(variable1,variable2)%>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(variableXXX, na.rm = TRUE),
           MissingCount = sum(is.na(variableXXX)))
```

NOTE: Assuming that we are interested in the count of `NA`s in the 'variableXXX' column grouped by 'variable1' and 'variable2'

---

If we need the NA count of the whole subset of dataset

```
library(purrr)
data %>% 
    group_split(variable1, variable2) %>%
    map_dfr(~ .x %>%
           summarise(Mean = mean(variableXXX, na.rm = TRUE), 
                     MissingCount = sum(is.na(.))))
```

Comment: I'd like to get the number of NA not only of the variableXXX, but of all the observations in each group